# Asp.Net MVC create view scaffolding from model is not generating int properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, integer, entity

When creating a view from a certain Model, noticed that Integer properties in a model is not generated in view. I watched some tutorials about MVC and they are all fine about generating integer properties. How do I fix this problem?

Here is some code of Student model and generated list view:(Not expecting the id should generated but TotalMarks is)

```
    [Table("Student")]
public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? TotalMarks { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
    @model IEnumerable<MVCTutorial.Models.Student>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: try item.ID instead of item.primarykey @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.ID  })

Comment: View generated by Scaffolding is basic tabular data representation of the source collection. You can edit it as per you needs like wise you can see commented code **/* id=item.PrimaryKey */** in the line **@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })** .

Comment: Maybe because (TotalMarks) is nullable (int?)

Comment: @Ala I dont think so because it was nullable in the tutorial which I have watched.

Comment: I tried the same using your Student entity but in my case it has generated both Name and TotalMarks. I did not get any problem.

Comment: @AnkitSahrawat yes thats what my problem is! It works for everyone but not for me...

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 is not scaffolding integer properties because i was not choosing any "Data Context Class" when creating a view. I chose the "Data Context Class" and problem solved. Now it is generating the TotalMarks property in view.